# Generating bitmaps by chance

Tags: android

How can I make a piece of code that will generate me my bitmaps by chance. I want a 50% chance for bitmap1, 50% for bitmap2 and 20% for bitmap3. Can I get some advice on how to do that?

I know how to do it for fifty-fifty:

```
Random r = new Random();
int randBall = r.nextInt(2);

if (randBall == 0) {
   return Gball;
} else if (randBall == 1) {
   return Bball;
}
```

But if I want to add one more ball with a 20% chance of spawning, I don't know how to do that.

Comment: that's 120% chances to get a bitmap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the java [Random.nextInt(int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28%29) method.
Call `nextInt(100);` and use

```
int p1 = 30;
int p2 = 50;

if ( n < p1 )
   return GBall;
else if ( n >= p1 && n < p1 + p2 )
   return BBall;
else // n < 100, always holds
   return RBall;
```

Comment: But if I want both to have 50% chance of spawning?

Comment: 50% + 50% = 100%, that would leave 0% for your third ball to spawn. But, using this method, you can make any distribution you want.

Comment: then you have a problem, as the third cannot have 20% chance to spawn if both firsts have 50% each. (or you seriously need some math 101)

Comment: what if i want chance number to be dynamic first is 30% than is 80%, i can't do that because in first if statment must be the lower one

Comment: Updated my answer. Strictly speaking the "n >= p1" part is not needed here, but it is if you need more if-clauses. Note that it doesn't matter if p1 > p2 or vice versa.

Answer (score 2):

So you have 120% in total :). But if you meant 50/30/20 distribution:

```
randBall = r.nextInt(10);
if (randBall < 5) return bitmap1;
else if (randBall < 8) return bitmap3;
else { return bitmap2; }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a floating point number:

```
r = random number between 0.0 and 1.0    
if (r < 0.2) { do something with 20% probability)}
else if (r < 0.9) {do something with 70% probability}
else {do something with remaining 10% probability}
```

Comment: But if I want both to have 50% chance of spawning or if I want chance number to be dynamic

Comment: @Itsmeyxc If you want the chance number to be dynamic, put the chances in variables. E.g. p1 = 0.2; p2 = 0.7 . The code then becomes `if ( r < p1 ) { ... } else if ( r < p1 + p2 ) { ... } else { ... }`.